# JSON object can not be inintialised

Tags: java, android, json

I am creating a `JSONObject` with the following code but the variable is showing `null` even after its initialization:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
try {
    jsonObject.put("username", "pradyut");
    jsonObject.put("password", "5F4DCC3B5AA765D61D8327DEB882CF99");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.i("log", "json exception : " + e.toString());
}


if (jsonObject == null) {
    Log.i("log", "the json object is not null");
    // this part is showing everytime.
} else {
    Log.i("log", "the json object is null");
}
```

I'm not getting any exception.

Why is that happening?

Comment: Your if statement condition is wrong. == null means it's checking if it is null.

Comment: No error running this code? Any Log/debug info?

Comment: You might consider using dictionary if you do not export to json?

Comment: *"but the variable is showing null even after its initialization"* No, it isn't. If you're saying that you're seeing the message `the json object is null`, it's because your `if` is backward. But you don't need the `if`; there's no possibility at all that `jsonObject` will be `null` at that point in that code.

Comment: yes . i was just checking . i am doing everything right . but the json object is not being initialized . why ?

Comment: Wait. (I deleted my answer) What? It's already in your code that you initialized it.

Comment: i know i have done everything right. but why the json object is null still ?

Comment: Try reversing your if condition to `jsonObject != null`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I thought he was about to add some further details. I'll undelete it.

Comment: @intj: Yeah, hopefully he does rather than just re-stating "I'm doing everything right" repeatedly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If he doesn't, this can be labeled as a typo and can be flagged.

Comment: @intj: Yup, I voted the same way. It's too bad. There's clearly some problem, but we can't help if the information isn't there...

Comment: i am extremely sorry for this . question . this is my mistake. on the == null condition it is written not null. this is why i was confused. i am so stupid.

Comment: @SagarNayak Everyone makes mistakes. Happy Coding! Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition is wrong.

```
if (jsonObject == null) {
    Log.i("log", "the json object is not null");
    // this part is showing everytime.
} else {
    Log.i("log", "the json object is null");
}
```

`jsonObject == null` is checking if it's null. If it is true, it will go through the the block, `else` otherwise. I think you intend to reverse the condition.

Comment: thanks . i was not looking at this part. but the log string was wrong .

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of having the wrong log statement for an `if-condition`. Your if-condition checks whether the object is null, yet the log statement prints `"the json object is not null"` which is utterly misleading.

Your if blocks should be like this:

```
  if (jsonObject != null) {
        Log.i("log", "the json object is not null");      
    } else {
        Log.i("log", "the json object is null");
    }
```

The lesson here is that instead of printing out a statement like "is not null" or "is null", rather print the actual variable itself - like `Log.i("jsonObject :"+jsonObject)` - then only if you need to do something based on the value, you can have `if(jsonObject !=null) {do-stuff}else{ log-error or -throw-some-exception}`.

Answer (score 0):

check this

change if condition 
 **if (jsonObject.length()!=0) {** it will help you

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("username","pradyut");
            jsonObject.put("password", "5F4DCC3B5AA765D61D8327DEB882CF99");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("log", "json exception : " + e.toString());
        }



        if (jsonObject.length()!=0) {
            Log.i("log", "the json object is not null");
            // this part is showing every time.
        } else {
            Log.i("log", "the json object is null");
        }
```

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say *what* you changed, and *why*. (That said, this question can't currently be reasonably answered. In its current state, since the OP has failed to clarify it, it should be closed and deleted instead.)

Comment: Thank you sir for your helpfull guide for me I will keep it in mind Thanks Again.

Answer (score -1):

Little blunder...change condition

```
 if (jsonObject != null) {
        Log.i("log", "the json object is not null");
        // this part is showing every time.
    } else {
        Log.i("log", "the json object is null");
    }
```

Comment: Hey Whatswrong here.. bro..